# Create aliases dynamically

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting, alias

I want to create aliases based on a command, its subcommands and its options. I'd like the alias to be the acronym of those components.

This is simpler to explain with the real example:

```
alias mc="mvn compile"
alias mt="mvn test"
alias mp="mvn package"
alias mi="mvn install"

alias mcc="mvn clean compile"
alias mct="mvn clean test"
alias mcp="mvn clean package"
alias mci="mvn clean install"

alias mcco="mvn clean compile --offline"
alias mcto="mvn clean test --offline"
alias mcpo="mvn clean package --offline"
alias mcio="mvn clean install --offline"
```

So I am trying to create a function to create aliases without having to copy paste all this commands if I want to add a new subcommand like `validate` it should be simple to create the relative aliases (`mv`, `mcv`, `mcvo`) or the same thing with a new option like `--debug` (`mccd`, `mctd`, `mcpd`, `mcid`).

I tried something like:

```
m="mvn "
c="clean "
p="package "
"`$m$c$p`" # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do be careful doing this.

Adding a `validate` command here will create an `mv` alias, shadowing the `mv` command used to move files. You may run into other naming conflicts.  My solution below provides some protection, but it won't help if you define an alias, and then add an executable of the same name to your `$PATH` afterwards. If you quote the command when running it (e.g. `"mv"`) that will prevent alias expansion and run the actual command, not the alias.

### On to the solution:

You can trim it by looping over the commands and just having one alias command per option set. For adding more alias sets on the fly, we can put the commands in a function:

```
gen_aliases() {
    local cmd="${1:?No command to create aliases for.}"
    local c=${cmd:0:1}
    which -s m${c} || alias m${c}="mvn $cmd"
    which -s mc${c} || alias mc${c}="mvn clean $cmd"
    which -s mc${c}o || alias mc${c}o="mvn clean $cmd --offline"
}

for cmd in compile test package install; do
    gen_aliases "$cmd"
done
```

`${parameter:?word}` is a parameter expansion that writes `word` to standard error and exits the function or script if `parameter` is unset or null. Gives us some sanity checking to make sure we don't create aliases if we weren't given a command to do it for.

`${parameter:offset:length}` is a parameter expansion that expands to `length` characters of `$parameter` starting at `offset`, so `${cmd:0:1}` gives us the first character of `$cmd`.

`which word` checks if `word` exists anywhere in `$PATH`. The `-s` silences it, so we just get the exit value (`0` if found, `1` if not found), which we then use with `||` to execute the `alias` commands only if `which` did **not** find `word` in `$PATH`.

Checking the results:

```
$ type mc
mc is aliased to `mvn compile'
$ type mcpo
mcpo is aliased to `mvn clean package --offline'
```

And adding another set of aliases:

```
$ gen_aliases validate
$ type mv
mv is /bin/mv
$ type mcv
mcv is aliased to `mvn clean validate'
```

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks for the warning about renaming `mv`. Is there a way to check programmatically if the alias command will shadow a system command or another alias?

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo You can use `which foo` to check if `foo` exists in `$PATH`. I've edited my answer to demonstrate that, and I've moved things into a function for added convenience.

Comment: btw even if -s silences it I get messages about all the aliases when I reload the shell.